# Electrons after Bremsstrahlung radiation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, x-rays

Where do electrons go after they have been braked in the Bremsstrahlung effect? In particular, those who have lost almost all their kinetic energy, could they be captured or interact with the nuclei?

Comment: In matter, they can simply become free electrons.

Answer (score 1):

*Bremsstrahlung* is a name for a general phenomenon, which may happen in many different situations. E.g., in [X-ray tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung#X-ray_tube) the electrons simply are collected by the anode.

The scenarios described in the OP are more characteristic of [Beta-decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung#Beta_decay) - in this case the answer is *yes, in some situations electrons are captured*.